# Number of leaves for lightgbm is smaller than categories in one feature

Tags: decision-trees, gbm, lightgbm

I was looking at a notebook someone posted for a Kaggle competition.  They use lightgbm with the number of leaves set to 40.  If I understand right, that's setting a limit on the size of the weak learners (decision trees) that are used in the boosting; the trees can't have more than 40 leaves.

However, after training, we see that the feature with the greatest feature importance is a categorical variable with 1000+ categories! If a branch were ever used in a decision tree for that variable, wouldn't it necessarily have at least 1000+ leaves?

How is this situation handled? When the number of leaves on the weak learners is smaller than the number of categories within one of the variables?

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to include categorical features, and in many of them a single leaf can combine multiple categories:

- With the label, target, or frequency encoding the categorical feature is effectively replaced by a numeric one, so a leaf can include multiple original categories naturally. Conversely, any numeric feature can be thought of as an ordinal categorical feature with an infinite number of possible values.
- With the hash or binary encoding a single bit is activated for different categories, grouping them together.
- LightGBM also [supports](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Features.html#optimal-split-for-categorical-features) categorical features natively. If they are marked in the configuration, LightGBM will consider various ways to partition all the categories of a given feature into two subsets.
- If the one-hot encoding is used, LightGBM can choose to combine multiple categories via the Exclusive Feature Bundling (EFB) algorithm. It is discussed in a [related question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/41907/88902).

Finally, it is also possible that only a few out of these 1000+ categories are really important (in reality or only seemingly due to overfitting).